# hierarchical query for all tables in a given schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to write a hierarchical query to show me all of the tables in a given schema from parents to children to grand children, etc. I split the code into a view and a query to hopefully make it more simple. I get back the parent tables, but none of the children or grandchildren.

Thanks

```
    CREATE VIEW tables_heirarchy_view
AS
WITH parent_table
AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
            rfc.constraint_catalog,          rfc.constraint_schema,    rfc.constraint_name,
            rfc.unique_constraint_catalog AS parent_constraint_catalog,
            rfc.unique_constraint_schema  AS parent_constraint_schema,
            rfc.unique_constraint_name    AS parent_constraint_name,
            tcp.table_catalog             AS parent_table_catalog,
            tcp.table_schema              AS parent_table_schema,
            tcp.table_name                AS parent_table_name
       FROM information_schema.referential_constraints   rfc
      INNER JOIN information_schema.table_constraints    tcp
         ON rfc.unique_constraint_catalog = tcp.constraint_catalog
        AND rfc.unique_constraint_schema  = tcp.constraint_schema
        AND rfc.unique_constraint_name    = tcp.constraint_name  )
SELECT tc.table_catalog,                    tc.table_schema,               tc.table_name,
       tc.constraint_type,                  tc.constraint_catalog,         tc.constraint_schema,
       tc.constraint_name,                  rfc.parent_constraint_catalog, rfc.parent_constraint_schema,
       rfc.parent_constraint_name,          rfc.parent_table_name
  FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
  LEFT OUTER JOIN parent_table              rfc
    ON tc.constraint_catalog               = rfc.constraint_catalog
   AND tc.constraint_schema                = rfc.constraint_schema
   AND tc.constraint_name                  = rfc.constraint_name
 WHERE tc.constraint_type IN ( 'PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY' )
 ORDER BY 1,2,3;

WITH RECURSIVE tables_heirarchy_with
    AS ( SELECT cur_view.sort_table_catalog,         cur_view.sort_table_schema,         cur_view.sort_table_name,
                cur_view.constraint_type,            cur_view.table_name,                cur_view.constraint_name,
                cur_view.parent_constraint_catalog,  cur_view.parent_constraint_schema,  cur_view.parent_table_name,
                cur_view.parent_constraint_name,     1 AS level
           FROM tables_heirarchy_view             AS cur_view
          WHERE cur_view.parent_table_name IS NULL
          UNION ALL
         SELECT child_rec.sort_table_catalog,        child_rec.sort_table_schema,        child_rec.sort_table_name,
                child_rec.constraint_type,           child_rec.table_name,               child_rec.constraint_name,
                child_rec.parent_constraint_catalog, child_rec.parent_constraint_schema, child_rec.parent_table_name,
                child_rec.parent_constraint_name,     child_rec.level + 1
           FROM tables_heirarchy_with             AS child_rec
           JOIN tables_heirarchy_view             AS parent_rec
             ON parent_rec.constraint_catalog  = child_rec.parent_constraint_catalog
            AND parent_rec.constraint_schema   = child_rec.parent_constraint_schema
            AND parent_rec.constraint_name     = child_rec.parent_constraint_name )
SELECT level, sort_table_catalog,         sort_table_schema,         sort_table_name,
              constraint_type,            table_name,                constraint_name,
              parent_constraint_catalog,  parent_constraint_schema,  parent_table_name
  FROM tables_heirarchy_with
 WHERE sort_table_schema = 'notereadercdi_ci'
 ORDER BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

Comment: Why this query would or wouldn't work depends entirely on what constraints are present and that they're named. I'd suggest including 2 CREATE TABLEs that you expect to produce 2 rows of output with level=1 and level=2.

Comment: I came from an Oracle background and writing hierarchical queries is better supported in Oracle. I was hoping that someone would respond who has worked with this type of query. I could write  sub-query for each level. But I don't yet know how many levels I need to write the query for. Using this type of query should work regardless of the number of levels in the ERD.

Comment: @AdamKG I took your advice and picked a table and its child tables and revamped the view to work for that. But in the recursive query I lose all of the child records when I set the base case as cur_view.parent_table_name IS NULL. Without that filter I don't have any records on level 2, 3, etc.

Comment: I meant to include the 2 CREATE TABLEs in the question, so that potential answerers are able to run your query and see the output. Doesn't have to be the entire tabledef, I'm just looking for a minimal runnable example. Recursive CTEs are the supported way of doing hierarchical queries - it shouldn't be a problem to get this working, it's just that why it's not currently working depends on what your constraint names are, and we have no way of guessing what those are. (A view shouldn't end up being required at all.)

Comment: I could make up an example with two tables. But since the query is going against data dictionary views, why couldn't someone run it against any database?

Comment: Because if you run it against an empty database, you'll get no rows in the result. If you run it against a database with 2 tables in a parent-child hierarchy and no constraints, you'll get no rows in the result. If you run it against a DB with 2 tables in a parent-table hierarchy and only primary key constraints, you'll get 2 rows with level=1. The only reason you'd get *anything* else, *ever*, is if those tables have constraints with specific names that satisfy the join conditions in your query. It's a data-dependent query and there's nothing we can do without the data.

Comment: But if I run it against a database and schema with 2 tables, it might work. If I run it against a database and schema with 20+ tables it might not work. Hence a simple example might not prove anything.